# Printed out items not in the array. ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I tried to sort items in the array, but it keeps printing out items that is not in the array.

```
def alphabetize(arr, rev=false)
  arr.sort!
  if rev == true
    puts arr.reverse!
  else
    puts arr
  end
end

numbers = [2, 5, 3, 16, 0, 322, -5]

puts alphabetize(numbers, true)
```

I expect the output to be the first line of code, but instead it prints out three lines.

```
[322, 16, 5, 3, 2, 0, -5]
34
["ants", "bees", "cockroaches"]
```

Comment: Where does animals come from?

Comment: That confuses me the most, they came from nowhere. ps. I am doing this on code academy.

Comment: Try running it in IRB.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the puts from code.

```rb
def alphabetize(arr, rev=false)
  arr.sort!
  if rev == true
    arr.reverse!
  else
    arr
  end
end
```

And run from irb console :

```
irb
```

Output

```
2.3.4 :001 > def alphabetize(arr, rev=false)
2.3.4 :002?>     arr.sort!
2.3.4 :003?>     if rev == true
2.3.4 :004?>         arr.reverse!
2.3.4 :005?>       else
2.3.4 :006 >           arr
2.3.4 :007?>       end
2.3.4 :008?>   end
 => :alphabetize
2.3.4 :009 > numbers = [2, 5, 3, 16, 0, 322, -5]
 => [2, 5, 3, 16, 0, 322, -5]
2.3.4 :010 > alphabetize(numbers, true)
 => [322, 16, 5, 3, 2, 0, -5]
2.3.4 :011 > animals = ["bees", "cockroaches", "ants"]
 => ["bees", "cockroaches", "ants"]
2.3.4 :012 > alphabetize(animals)
 => ["ants", "bees", "cockroaches"]
```

Is there the output yo expect?

Comment: I was expecting [322, 16, 5, 3, 2, 0, -5]. It worked after removing the puts, thank you! But it still confuses me where did the animals come from.

Comment: Hi Helen i think i found the issue,

Answer (score 0):

Hi Helen i think i found the issue,
and i think its bug from codeacademy
if you write this way, it return success

TL;DR

wrong code

```
def alphabetize(arr, rev=false)
  rev ? arr.reverse! : arr.sort!
end
```

right code

```
def alphabetize(arr, rev=false)
  rev ? arr.reverse! : arr.sort!
end

numbers = [5, 1, 3, 8]
puts alphabetize(numbers)
```

Comment: I think you are right. The solution you gave in the prior answer worked perfectly. What does the "?" and ":" mean in your latest code?

Comment: Hi Helen, its ternary operator. It's useful if you're "oneliner". Please read this article below for further information : https://www.rubyguides.com/2018/07/ruby-operators/#Ruby_Ternary_Operator